# Using a python Project in java

Tags: java, python, nlp

I am using java in order to build a linguistic System for arabic language and i need to use an open source project as a black box inside my System the only problem is that the open source System is in Python so my question how could i use this System in java,
so that i could make this function

```
String output=applyPythonSystem(String input);
```

And please don't say Jython (Without explaining How??) i tried to use it but i couldn't find a way to do this function

Comment: Have a look at this: [Can we call a python method from java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460468/can-we-call-a-python-method-from-java)

Comment: it works if there is a single python class but it gives Error when i import in python
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mishkal-source//aranalex//analex.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pyarabic.araby as araby  # basic arabic text functions
ImportError: No module named pyarabic

Comment: To fix this error you must find out how imports work in Python. I guess you have to search for "relative imports". Making your java project work ist just a matter of knowing how to execute your Python program the right way.